# React - only/best way to return a className value that features JavaScript & string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is this the only/best way to return a `className`'s value when dealing with JavaScript & string? To make it be the execution of a function?

```
export default function App() {
  let [shape, setShape] = useState(false);

  function returnClassNameValue() {
    let value = "color";
    if (shape) {
      value += " shape";
    }
    return value;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className={returnClassNameValue()}></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-leaf-gp98s?file=/src/App.js:76-369) of the same code.

For instance, I tried to write something like this which doesn't work:

```
<div className=`color ${shape ? "shape" : null}`></div>
```

Comment: When writing JSX any template literals inside will be evaluated as strings. You have to put braces `{}` around for them to be evaluated as a javascript expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second option, in my opinion, is better, but you need to use brackets.
Look at this example:

```
// App.js file
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [shape, setShape] = useState(false);

  function returnClassNameValue() {
    let value = "color";
    if (shape) {
      value += " shape";
    }
    return value;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className={`color ${shape ? "shape" : ''`}></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Do you know anywhere in react docs an example of this is mentioned? I suppose it satisfies the rule that '1 JavaScript expression' may be used as value to an attribute.

Comment: In JSX, every js code must be into brackets

Answer (score 0):

You need to use curly brackets in this case, and replace `null` with empty string or it will render in markup.

```js
<div className={`color ${shape ? "shape" : ''}`}></div>
```

If you use function, when it is better to use with `useMemo` in order to avoid unnecessary renders

```js
export default function App() {
  let [shape, setShape] = useState(false);

  let className = useMemo(() => {
    let value = "color";
    if (shape) {
      value += " shape";
    }
    return value;
  }, [shape]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={className}></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

But in my opinion most convenient way to handle classes is to use `classnames` package, your example will look like this

```js
import cn from 'classnames';

export default function App() {
  let [shape, setShape] = useState(false);

  
  return (
    <>
      <div className={cn('color', {'shape': shape})}></div>
    </>
  );
}
```